# Qt thread two arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I want built my Qt application with using QThread, because I want to separate long process form MainWindow to thread.

I've a problem in this code:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void doWork(const std::string &param2, std::string &param2) {
        int result;
        /* ... here is the expensive or blocking operation ... */
        emit resultReady(result);
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(const int &result);
};

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::input,&Controller::output, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        workerThread.start();
    }
    ~Controller() {
        workerThread.quit();
        workerThread.wait();
    }
public slots:
    void handleResults(const int &);
private:
    string input;
    string output;
};
```

I want that my code can transfer two value (input, output) strings to QThread and as the result emit signals as int value. But, listed code don't work. I looking for solution looks like blackgroundWorker in .Net and has similar functionality.

Should I do it?

**EDIT**

I cannot compile this. I got error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const': cannot convert argument 2 from 'std::string Controller::* ' to 'const char *'   GPCTool C:\repo\Tool\Controller.cpp 21
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Don't work" Does it not compile?. Does it crash? Does it give unexpected results?

Comment: I got error code, that I wrote in EDIT

Comment: Well, it seems that your second `connect` has too many parameters, doesn't it?

Comment: This line looks strange: `connect(this, &Controller::input,&Controller::output, worker, &Worker::doWork);`

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`, and you haven't shown the declarations of `Controller::input()` and `Controller::output()`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: If `Controller::input` and `Controller::output` are both signals with the approproate signature, and you want to connect them both to `doWork`, just split that `connect` into two. Otherwise please explain what exactly did you want to achieve with this line: `connect(this, &Controller::input,&Controller::output, worker, &Worker::doWork);`

Comment: I did mistake. I've corrected code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this line of code will not work:

```
connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
```

`workerThread` lives in your main thread, while `worker` lives in the thread handled by (created by) `workerThread`. So when `QThread::finished` is fired, `QObject::deleteLater` will be called asynchronously (see `Qt::AutoConnection`), however has the thread is already finish, the asynchronous call will never complete.

And it even get worse. Even if `QObject::deleteLater` is called, the deferred delete will never occur, for the same reason: the thread is already finished.

---

```
connect(this, &Controller::input, &Controller::output, worker, &Worker::doWork);
```

This call does not match any prototype of `connect()`. You cannot connect variables to slots.

Either create an intermediate signal:

```
class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QThread workerThread;
public:
    Controller() {
        Worker *worker = new Worker;
        worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
        connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);
        connect(this, &Controller::callDoWork, worker, &Worker::doWork);
        connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
        workerThread.start();
        emit callDoWork(input, output);
    }
    ~Controller() {
        workerThread.quit();
        workerThread.wait();
    }
signals:
    emit callDoWork(std::string, str::string);
public slots:
    void handleResults(const int &);
private:
    string input;
    string output;
};
```

or use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`:

```
Controller() {
    Worker *worker = new Worker;
    worker->moveToThread(&workerThread);
    connect(&workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &QObject::deleteLater);

    connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
    workerThread.start();
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(worker, "doWork", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(std::string, input), Q_ARG(std::string, output));
}
```

Note that for these 2 solutions to work you need to register `std::string` with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE and qRegisterMetaType (see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE).

And you also want to replace `std:string &output` by `std::string *output`, as Qt will make a copy of `output` between both threads and you will not see the change reflected to the original `output` variable.

---

```
connect(worker, &Worker::resultReady, this, &Controller::handleResults);
```

This does not compile because the signature of `resultReady` does not match `handleResults`. To connect a signal to a slot they must take the same parameters.

I suggest you read [Qt Signal & Slots documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

---

Regarding your use of threads, I think you should take a look at [QThreadPool](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html) and [QRunnable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html).

Comment: connect(this, &Controller::input, &Controller::output, worker, &Worker::doWork); In this line I want transfer output and input string as parameters to doWork method

Comment: I've updated my answer. You should definitely take the time to read Qt signal and slot documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use first way, and I'll read more abut slots and signals :).

Answer (score 0):

You likely read the stupid blog that claims one has to create a worker object and use it with a plain thread, instead of simply deriving from `QThread` and implementing `run()`.

Since your workload is exactly just a single function needed only once, it is way easier to do just that.

In either case just pass the values to the class by constructor or setter methods, there is really no need to pass them as arguments to `doWork()`

Comment: Because it claims to be "the way" of using `QThread` it is stupid, because there is no such thing as a single way.
Using a worker with `moveToThread` is a nice option for when the worker is doing event loop based work. It is just unnecessary coding overhead if the worker is running a single function or endless loop, additional to the complexity of having to deal with two objects instead of one.